# python: how to convert currency to decimal?

Tags: python

i have dollars in a string variable

```
dollars = '$5.99'
```

how do i convert this to a decimal instead of a string so that i can do operations with it like adding dollars to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an easy approach:

```
dollar_dec = float(dollars[1:])
```

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to store currency as a float. You can lose precision and expose your data to rounding errors quite easily. Now, if you're looking to Superman III some extra money and funnel it into a side account you own...

Comment: AKA Office Space; if you're lucky you won't end up having to burn down the building.

Answer (score 28):

If you'd prefer just an integer number of cents:

```
cents_int = int(round(float(dollars.strip('$'))*100))
```

If you want a Decimal, just use...

```
from decimal import Decimal
dollars_dec = Decimal(dollars.strip('$'))
```

If you know that the dollar sign will always be there, you could use `dollars[1:]` instead of `dollars.strip('$')`, but using `strip()` lets you also handle strings that omit the dollar sign (`5.99` instead of `$5.99`).

Comment: If you prefer an integer number of cents, keep it integral all the way: `d, c = dollars.strip('$').split('.', 2); cents = int(d) * 100 + int(c.strip()[:2])`.  Of course, this assumes you want to round fractional cents toward 0 (insert Superman III joke of choice here).

Comment: The decimal option is the one to take.  I'd make a 2 cents joke but it's late.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming the string stored in the variable `dollars` was generated using python's locale module. A potentially cleaner way to convert it back to float (decimal) is to use the `atof` function from the same module. It should work as long as you use the same `setlocale` parameters in both directions (from currency to string and vice-versa).

for instance:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
value = 122445.56
value_s = locale.currency(value, grouping=True)
#generates $122,445.56
```

to convert it back:

```
value2 = locale.atof(value_s[1:])
#value2 = 122445.56 
value == value2 #True
```

Comment: This is the only answer that takes into account the possibility of commas as thousands separators, but it also converts to a float instead of a Decimal which causes a loss of precision.

Answer (score 8):

I know this an old question, but this is a very simple approach to your problem that's easily readable:

for:

```
dollars = '$5.99'
dollars = dollars.replace("$","").replace(",","")
/* 5.99 */
```

It also works with a larger number that might have a comma in it:

```
dollars = '1,425,232.99'
dollars = dollars.replace("$","").replace(",","")
/* 1425232.99 */
```

Comment: That still has it as a string at the end.

Comment: end it with... dollars = float(dollars) ...and you're fine

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use Decimal:

```
from decimal import Decimal
dollars = Decimal(dollars.strip('$'))
```

From there adding is pretty simple

```
dollars += 1 # Would add 1 to your decimal
```

Answer (score 3):

Through decimal package

```
>>> dollars = '$5.99'
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(dollars[1:])
Decimal('5.99')
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only going to be adding (and not multiplying or dividing) consider just storing cents instead of dollars and not using the decimal package.  I suggest using the simplest tool for the job, and decimal doesn't provide any value if you are just adding dollars and cents.

Answer (score 0):

First, strip off the '$' character. If it's always consistently the first character, that's easy:

```
dollars[1:]
```

To keep the cents perfect without worrying about the non-perfect representation of cents in floating point, you'll want to use Decimal values:

```
from decimal import *
Decimal(dollars[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep moneys in cents for easy rounding and sometimes '$' is missing:

```
for dollars in ('$5.99','6.77'):
    cents = int(float((dollars[1:] if dollars.startswith('$') else dollars))*100)
    print '%s = %i cents = %i dollars and %i cents' % ((dollars, cents)+divmod(cents, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example of converting a messy currency string into a decimal rounded down to the cent:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

messy = ',   $1, 111.2199  ,,,'

less_messy = Decimal(''.join(messy.replace(',','').split()).replace('$',''))
converted = less_messy.quantize(Decimal(".01"), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)

print(converted)
1111.21
```

Other rounding options include: `ROUND_HALF_UP`, `ROUND_HALF_DOWN`, `ROUND_UP`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Amar's answer above but using decimal instead of float:

```
from decimal import *
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )

converted = locale.atof("$100,000".strip("$"), func=Decimal)
print(converted) 
#prints 100000

print(type(converted)) 
#prints <class 'decimal.Decimal'>

print(locale.currency(converted, grouping = True)) 
#prints $100,000.00
```