# In Python how to strip dollar signs and commas from dollar related fields only

Tags: python, regex

I'm reading in a large text file with lots of columns, dollar related and not, and I'm trying to figure out how to strip the dollar fields ONLY of $ and , characters.

so say I have:

```
a|b|c

$1,000|hi,you|$45.43

$300.03|$MS2|$55,000
```

where a and c are dollar-fields and b is not.
The output needs to be:

```
a|b|c

1000|hi,you|45.43

300.03|$MS2|55000
```

I was thinking that regex would be the way to go, but I can't figure out how to express the replacement:

```
f=open('sample1_fixed.txt','wb')

for line in open('sample1.txt', 'rb'):
    new_line = re.sub(r'(\$\d+([,\.]\d+)?k?)',????, line)
    f.write(new_line)

f.close()
```

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first fundamental task is to define in rigorous terms what is a "dollar field" and what isn't. If a dollar field isn't defined as a field whose first character is a dollar sign, what is the definition? Once you have that definition you can make a lot more progress.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: He gave the expected result in the second code block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = '\$\d+(,|\.)?\d+'
>>> s = '$1,000|hi,you|$45.43'
>>> '|'.join(i.translate(None, '$,') if re.match(exp, i) else i for i in s.split('|'))
'1000|hi,you|45.43'
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are really tied to the idea of using a regex, I would suggest doing something simple, straight-forward, and generally easy to read:

```
def convert_money(inval):
    if inval[0] == '$':
        test_val = inval[1:].replace(",", "")
        try:
            _ = float(test_val)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            inval = test_val

    return inval


def convert_string(s):
    return "|".join(map(convert_money, s.split("|")))


a = '$1,000|hi,you|$45.43'
b = '$300.03|$MS2|$55,000'

print convert_string(a)
print convert_string(b)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1000|hi,you|45.43
300.03|$MS2|55000
```

Comment: Of course, if you have values like `$122,1.00,11` then this would convert it to `1221.0011` which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regexx

```
((?<=\d),(?=\d))|(\$(?=\d))
```

eg

```
import re
>>> x="$1,000|hi,you|$45.43"
re.sub( r'((?<=\d),(?=\d))|(\$(?=\d))', r'', x)
'1000|hi,you|45.43'
```

Comment: @Rachel S How about now

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex and then replace the matched strings with `\1\2\3`

```
\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:(?:,(\d{2}))*(?:,(\d{3})))?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wM0zB6/3)

Answer (score 0):

I Try this regex take if necessary.

```
\$(\d+)[\,]*([\.]*\d*)
```

**SEE DEMO :** http://regex101.com/r/wM0zB6/2

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are addressing the entire line of text at once.  I think your first task would be to break up your string by columns into an array or some other variables.  Once you've don that, your solution for converting strings of currency into numbers doesn't have to worry about the other fields.

Once you've done that, I think there is probably an easier way to do this task than with regular expressions.  You could start with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887469/python-how-to-convert-currency-to-decimal).

If you really want to use regex though, then this pattern should work for you:

```
\[$,]\g
```

[Demo on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/cG9mE5/1)

Replace matches with empty strings.  The pattern gets a little more complicated if you have other kinds of currency present.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a black list and checking if the characters are in it, is an easy way to do this:

```
blacklist = ("$", ",") # define characters to remove
with open('sample1_fixed.txt','wb') as f:
    for line in open('sample1.txt', 'rb'):
        clean_line = "".join(c for c in line if c not in blacklist)
        f.write(clean_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\$(?=(?:[^|]+,)|(?:[^|]+\.))
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.Use `re.M` option.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/gT6kI4/6