# How to convert Euro currency string to float number?

Tags: python, floating-point, locale, currency-formatting, euro

I need to convert a string currency string in Continental Europe format into a  float number:

Input:

```
'6.150.593,22 €'
```

Realize that decimal point is comma, and thousands separators are period characters.

Output:

```
6150593.22
```

I'd read these questions, but they only works for US dollar currency and locale:

- [How do I convert a currency string to a floating point number in
  Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421922/how-do-i-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-floating-point-number-in-python)
- [python: how to convert currency to decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887469/python-how-to-convert-currency-to-decimal)

```
currency_euros='6.150.593,22 €'
float(currency_euros[:-2])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    float(currency_euros[:-2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.150.593,22'
```

**Updated:** Following the @IrmendeJong answer:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "es")
'es'
>>> print(locale.currency(6150593.22))
6150593,22 €
>>> money = '6.150.593,22 €'
>>> locale.atof(money)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    locale.atof(money)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\locale.py", line 318, in atof
    return func(delocalize(string))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6150593.22 €'
>>>
```

I'm ashtonished that `locale.currency()` works fine but its reciprocal method `locale.atof()` doesn't work.

Comment: Simply remove all dots and replace the comma with a dot. Strip off non float characters

Comment: Check out the `locale` module.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html

Comment: Yes, I know how to eliminate the  Eur(€) symbol for a string, but at this moment, the question is that locale.atof() doesn't support the currency symbol character.

Comment: Do note that if you are using this in a financial application, the ``float`` datatype is actually not the best choice (because it loses precision). ``decimal.Decimal`` is better but it's a bit harder to parse then because you won't be able to use ``locale.atof``. I guess you'll have to convert the thousands separator and decimal comma yourself to something that ``decimal.Decimal("...")`` understands

Answer (score 10):

Use `locale.atof` https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.atof

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC,"nl")
'nl'
>>> locale.atof("6.150.593,22")
6150593.22
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the `locale.atof()` method but it doesn't work with de Eur(€) symbol while the reciprocal method `locale.currency()` seems to support it.  I've updated my question.

Comment: ``atof`` is for parsing a number. Any currency symbol(s) are not part of the actual number. It depends on the situation and application how they are represented! For instance, in some systems I've encountered € in front, at the end, or ``EUR`` in front or at the end, separated by either one or more tabs and/or spaces. It's up to you I guess to strip off the currency symbol so you only pass the actual number string to ``atof``.

Answer (score 3):

A good way of doing it (1 line) :

```
NewValue = float(value[:-2].replace(".", "").replace(",","."))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value = '6.150.593,22 €'
value = value.split()[0]              #Take out euro symbol
integer, decimal = value.split(',')   #Separate integer and decimals
integer = integer.replace('.','')     #Take out dots
final_value = int(integer) + (int(decimal) * (10**(-len(decimal))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution may be as follows:

```
>>> val = '6.150.593,22 €'
>>> res = val[:-2].split(',')
>>> float('.'.join([res[0].replace('.', ''), res[1]]))
6150593.22
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import decimal, locale, re
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'es_ES.UTF8')
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'es_ES.UTF8')
>>> locale.currency(6150593.22)
'6150593,22 €'
>>> re.sub('[^(\d,.)]', '', locale.currency(6150593.22))
'6150593,22'
>>> 6150593.22 == locale.atof(re.sub('[^(\d,.)]', '', locale.currency(6150593.22)))
True
>>> decimal.Decimal(locale.atof(re.sub('[^(\d,.)]', '', locale.currency(6150593.22))))
Decimal('6150593.219999999739229679107666015625')
```

Works as "revert what currency() did to my float" for a lot of locales I've tested.

Bonus: Converted do Decimal