# Entire list of options for "locale" option for locale.setlocale() method

Tags: python-3.x, data-conversion

I don't know about anyone else but this is exceptionally frustrating.  I'm looking for the entire list of options I can use for `locale` option in method `locale.setlocale()`.  I've seen a list of some examples like "en_US.UTF8" and "de" and "fr_FR".  Where is the entire list of options I can use?

Python documentation:

[locale.setlocale()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale)

Stack Overflow examples:

[example 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421922/how-do-i-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-floating-point-number-in-python)
[example 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717037/how-to-convert-euro-currency-string-to-float-number)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code) is a good place to start - anyway, seems to depend on what is defined on the machine you run this on.