# How to write a regex on python to find values between 2 and 2,000,000,000?

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm trying to write a regex that will find currency values in my text. I have values that vary from 2 dollars to 2,240,000,000. I'm trying to write a regex expression that will find all these values, but I'm failing hard. I tried something like:

```
^\{USD}?(\d*(\d\.?|\.\d{1,2}))$
```

but didn't work. I appreciate any help :)

EDIT: For clarification, I have a text with several dollar values in it, ranging from 2 ~ 2,000,000,000.

The text is something like:

"The base purchase is USD 2,00. (...) The amount equal to US 2,300,000 which refers to the premium package. (...) The country needs USD 300,00..."

I want to find and extract these values (USD + numbers) and save it to a list, each value as a different element. Thank you

Comment: Since you're using Python, what would be wrong with just comparing the number directly against your range boundaries, using inequality operators `<` and `>`?  If you're starting with a text number, then just cast it first.

Comment: Could you clarify more specifically what you want it to match? In same places, they represent numbers with, for example, 2.240.000.000,00. Do you want it to match that?

Comment: relate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887469/python-how-to-convert-currency-to-decimal

Comment: I edited my question, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple things are wrong in your expression :
`^\{USD}?(\d*(\d\.?|\.\d{1,2}))$`

1. `\{USD}?` in regex language this would mean: expect the `{` literal character followed by `USD` followed by the character `}` if any. If you want to have an optional group `USD` you have to use parenthesis without `\`: `(USD)?`. You can use a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) for this : `(?:USD)?`.

This would give : `^(USD)?(\d*(\d\.?|\.\d{1,2}))$`

2. `(\d\.?|\.\d{1,2})`, the whole group should be repeated in order to match the entire string : `(\d\.?|\.\d{1,2})*`

This would give : `^(USD)?(\d*(\d\.?|\.\d{1,2})*)$`

3. `\d\.?`: if this is supposed to match the part with a thousand separator it should be a comma not a point regarding your example: `\d*,?`

This would give : `^(USD)?(\d*(\d,?|\.\d{1,2})*)$`

4. `(\d*(\d`: this won't work, the second `\d` will never match because all digit will be consumed by the first `\d*`, you could use the non-greedy operator `?` like this: `(\d*?(\d` but it's not pretty.

This would give : `^(USD)?(\d*?(\d,?|\.\d{1,2})*)$` which may work for you, but looks less than optimal.

An alternative would be to build your regular expression without an "or" clause using the following parts :

1. The prefix : "USD ", optional and with optional space : `(USD ?)?`
2. The integral part of the amount before the thousand separators: `\d+`
3. The integral part of the amount with a thousand separator, optional and repeatable: `(,\d+)*`
4. The decimal part, optional : `(\.\d+)?`

Wich would give something like that: `(USD ?)?(\d+)(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?`

You can test it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/?regex=(USD%20?)?(%5Cd%2B)(,%5Cd%2B)*(.%5Cd%2B)?&testString=USD+5,123,456.25)

You can further restrict the number of digits in each parts to avoid false-positive :

```
(USD ?)?(\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?
```

A final version would be optimized with [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) unless necessary:

```
(?:USD ?)?(?:\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?
```

Edit: the test case you provided uses incoherent use of decimal separators (sometime ".", sometimes ","). If you really want to match that, you can use a character class like this :

```
(?:USD ?)?(?:\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?
```

Which matches every number in your example :
[image: Regex 101 screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer sir. It is very complete, I really learned from it. One more thing, since the prefix "USD" is an option, can I also edit the regex to find "USD" and/or "INR"?

Comment: @Vanj yes, in this case, it's relevant to use an or case like this : `((USD|INR|EUR) ?)?(\d+)(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start with

```
import re
text = "The base purchase is USD 2,00.00 (...) The amount equal to US 2,300,000 which refers to the premium package. (...) The country needs USD 300,00..."
```

As, @zakinster proposed, you can find the string numbers that interest you with :

```
regex = r"(?:USD)?(?:\d+,)*\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
numbers = re.findall(regex, text)
```

Then, to filter the one you've mentionned :

```
def toInteger(s): return int(s.split('.')[0].replace(',',''))

def numberBetween(string,lowerBound,upperBound): 
    intValue = toInteger(string)
    return True if intValue>lowerBound & intValue<upperBound else False

print(list(filter(lambda x: numberBetween(x,2,2240000000),numbers)))
```

should give you what you want :

```
['2,00.00', '2,300,000', '300,00']
```